# Unable to save Excel from C# project

Tags: c#, excel

why am I with my code unable to save modified Excel sheet?

I have tryed several approachs but none of them worked. It is overwhelming for me at this point, can anyone help?

The thing is I don't really know whether `excelWorksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value = currentName;` writes the "test" into the cell...

The code:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlFilePath);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = OfficeOpenXml.LicenseContext.Commercial;
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(excelFilePath))
            using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(fs))
            {
                ExcelWorkbook excelWorkBook = excelPackage.Workbook;
                ExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet = excelWorkBook.Worksheets.First();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "a" )
                    {
                        //reader.MoveToAttribute("stat");
                        string currentName = "test";
                        label_infoAboutOutput.Text = currentName;
                        for(int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
                        {
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)excelWorksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value))
                                    excelWorksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value = currentName;
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }

                //excelPackage.SaveAs(ms);
                reader.Close();
                ms.Close();
                fs.Close();
                excelPackage.Save();
                
            }
```

Comment: What _specifically_ isn't working? Is an exception being thrown? Did you debug through it, line by line? Did it get to the line doing the assignment when you debugged it?

Comment: Given you used `File.OpenRead` (read, not write) I can't see anywhere that can possibly _write_ the file contents.

Comment: https://riptutorial.com/epplus shows an example of dealing with an existing file. Have you tried that technique?

Comment: @mjwills yes, the debugger read all the code and no exception is thrown, it just doesn't affect the excel sheet

Comment: You are trying to save after closing all the streams, so even if you opened the file with read/write permissions..... You still wouldn't be able to save

Comment: @Sidewinder94 Exactly. Hopefully the OP can click the link I provided and try interacting with the file _directly_.

Comment: thank you, I'll try this, looks like I have to remake it

Comment: @mjwills yep, the link was helpful, sorry if the question looked dump, I really got stuck on such simple thing, my approach was just bad

Comment: All good - great to see you got it solved.